# What is obtained from the product of a probability and a log probability ratio?

Tags: probability, neural-networks, logit

I'm looking at the commonly used artificial neural network model that has nodes and connections.

Quick refresher

1. A connection has a source and target node, and a weight. The output of the source node is multiplied by the weight to give the connection's output value.
2. A node sums the value of each connection feeding into it, and applies a sigmoid activation function. This is the node's output value.
3. A commonly used activation function is the [logistic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function).

I'm just exploring some ideas around this commonly used model. So for instance, the [logistic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) is the inverse of the [logit function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit). That's interesting because the [logit function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) is commonly used to calculate a log-odds from a probability. Therefore if we work backwards we can think of the summed input into the activation function as being a log-odds value.

So let's say we have one input node (x), one output (y), and one connection (w) then we have:

```
y = logitInverse(xw)
```

(logitInverse being the sigmoid logistic function, same thing).

We've inputed xw into logitInverse() function, so in one sense we are treating xw as a log-odds value. But x was the output from a previous node so is from the output of a previous node's logitInverse() and it can therefore be considered to be a probability with range [0,1]. Hence we have multiplied a probability (x) with a log-odds (w) and treated the result as a log-odds (the input to logitInverse).

Regarding w. This definitely hints at being amenable to being treated as a log-odds value since the range 'fits', e.g. typically a weight would be observed to be in the range [-5,5] (but could go far beyond that), but crucially a weight of zero corresponds with a probability of 50% [ consider log(50/50) = 0 ], i.e. the target node is not correlated with the source node.

So everything sort of fits, except we multiply a probability (x) with a log-odds (w) and treat it as a log-odds.

Final thought. Again, taking w to be a log-odds value, then we can write it as:

```
w = log(a/b)
```

And we multiply xw, therefore we have:

```
xw = x * log(a/b) = log((a/b)^x)
```

I have no idea if that has any significance on the question or not.

Comment: You have a lot of background here, can you clarify your actual question?

Comment: (Also note that the logit is not used to calculate a log probability, the logit transformation converts a probability into the log odds.)

Comment: I very specifically used the term 'log probability ratio'; is it more common place to refer to it as log probability odds? (I think of 'odds' as being old fashioned terminology, but that might be just me). The title question pretty much covers it - what actually is the value that we get by multiplying a probability with a log probability odds? Is it another log probability odds? or something else?

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed the "ratio". That isn't standard, though. It is definitely conventional to refer to "odds". I'm not sure I've ever heard "probability ratio". To me that connotes *risk ratio*, which is definitely not the same thing as odds.

Comment: @gung Thanks. I've updated the Q to use the term 'log-odds'.

Comment: i think you should just read up on logistic regression to understand the modelling approach.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it is any specific kind of animal, in the sense that [probabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability) and [odds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds) are specific kinds of things.  I think its just a number.

(I'll admit that this doesn't seem like much of an answer, but I don't think there's anything more to it than that.)

---

*Edit:* I may still be misreading this, but let me note that `w` is not a log-odds, it is just some number that is adjusted throughout the training of the neural network to optimize the network's predictive accuracy.  It could be anything.  In your setup, `xw` is treated as though it were a log odds, in the sense that `xw` is passed through the logistic / inverse logit function.  Then, `y` becomes a number that is like a probability in the sense that it now varies within the interval $(0,\ 1)$.  For completeness, if we are moving from the input layer to the hidden layer, `x` could be any number as well (in many machine learning contexts, `x` is a binary feature indicator—`0/1`—but it could be a continuous value).  If we are moving from the hidden layer to the output layer, your new `x` is your old `y`, so it can be thought of as analogous to a probability.